# How to publicly expose package interface cleanly? Relative imports are polluting the namespace

Tags: python, python-import, python-packaging, relative-import, vscode-python

I want to create a clean package namespace so when user types
`pkg.mod` they only see `left` and `right` in autocomplete. However I cannot figure out how to avoid autocomplete showing `thing` package name. I am using VSCode. How can I correct this?

Problem:

[image]

Directory structure

```
pkg/
   mod/
      __init__.py
      thing.py
   __init__.py
```

`/mod/thing.py`

```
left = 5
right = 5
```

`/mod/__init__.py`

```
__all__ = ['left','right']
from .thing import left, right
```

`/__init__.py`

```
__all__ =['mod']

from . import mod
```

Comment: Maybe it is a VSCode issue. -- Your Python code seems correct enough to me, although I can not say I ever deeply investigated this. You also have to be aware of what exactly `__all__` does, which is not much. And of course you need to remember that in Python everything is public (for some definition of "public").